# Concatenate string and integer in VB

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a following code:

```
Dim IDfiltr As Long
IDfiltr = Forms!KONTROLA!ID_OS
DoCmd.OpenForm "OSOBA", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal
Forms!OSOBA.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Forms]![OSOBA]![ID_OS] Like " & IDfiltr
```

In the last line, I am trying to substitute the VBA variable IDfiltr into the expression of the `DoCmd.ApplyFilter`, but it doesn't work. I was also trying this:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Forms]![OSOBA]![ID_OS] Like IDfiltr"
```

But it also doesn't work. How can I substitute the VB variable IDfiltr into the expression?

Comment: Why it's not working for the first solution ? Error message ? Can you do a `Msgbox IDfiltr` and tell the result ?

Comment: Not error message but empty form. Msgbox tells the IDfiltr value correctly. The problem is how to use a variable inside a command?

Comment: For me the first concatenation should work :/ If you print it for debug, is it the right command ?

Comment: I solved it. The problem was `[Forms]` in the command. The right code is `DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[OSOBA]![ID_OS] Like " & IDfiltr`

Answer (score 2):

The LIKE command works on strings. You also need to code this so you tell the LIKE command what part of the string you want to match. For example's sake, suppose you want to match the Long variable to the beginning of a string:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Forms]![OSOBA]![ID_OS] Like '" & CStr(IDfiltr) & "*'"
```

So if field [ID_OS] is a string, this will match all records where IDfiltr is the beginning of field [ID_OS].

While my answer is technically correct, I have a feeling you really intend to do something else. [ID_OS] is probably an Integer or Long, and you really want some other outcome.